# Best way to delay each iteration in python multi thread?

Tags: python, concurrency

Here's the snippet

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    results = executor.map(upload, df.to_dict('records'))
       for r in results:
           t.append(r)
```

Now there's a limit say only 5 uploads per minute. I want to give 1 minute delay after each iteration. Wonder best way to do it? Add sleep() before the loop?

Comment: Could you wrap upload in a custom function that just sleeps once it's done uploading?

Comment: thanks for the idea. I just used a decorator that calls upload with delay. seems to work.